# How to setup ExternalDNS on Microk8s cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, dns, servers

I have a Highly Available, 3 nods, Microk8s cluster with MetalLB and Ingress.

The cluster is supposed to serve a website with high availability.

I want to enable ExternalDNS for the website with the domain currently on Cloudflare (but I’m open to other free/commercial alternatives).

I have looked at the examples on the [ExternalDNS repository](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns) but I can’t find any instructions for a similar setup.

Can anyone point me to a starting point, please?

Answer (score 0):

cloudflare DNS can be managed by external DNS setup, did you tried this, I have worked with this with DNS on digital ocean

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/cloudflare.md

Comment: Did you use it with Microk8s? I ask because I keep reading that ExtranalDNS relies on an `etcd` cluster which is not available in the default setup of Microk8s.

Answer (score 0):

Run an application and expose it via a Kubernetes Service:

Example for nginx: example.org as a external DNS